# WP-CLI not working in Linux using Local By Flywheel [Error: Error establishing a database connection.]

Tags: wordpress

What is happening is that the database connection is correct and I am able to use the site perfectly, but when I run any wp-cli command, including the custom one I am creating, it returns the error Error: Error establishing a database connection.

I want a solution so that the error goes away Please

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal using the *Open site shell* link.

Make sure the gnome-terminal is installed.